# Window UWP best practice to show desired content on app start

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp

I am currently teaching myself how to build a Windows UWP app.

*My question is:*
If I have an app which requires a login, how do I handle the decision if a login-form should be shown, or the actual start page of the app if the `PasswordVault` already has stored credentials?

Do I leave the MainPage blank and just write the logic (in the .cs-file) which decides if I navigate to the LoginPage or to the ContentPage (or whatever I will call it)?
Or is it the intention to put this logic into the App.xaml.cs?

Or is my approach totally wrong and this should be handled in a complete different way?

Comment: Are you familiar with MVVM? I usually use `VisualStateManager` combined with viewmodel to hide/show content

Comment: Yes but, I would like to avoid rendering content which in 98% of the time the app is used will not be used at all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show hide content based on a ViewModel you could add a property to your ViewModel say IsLoggedIn

```
private bool isLoggedIn;
public bool IsLoggedIn
{
   get { return isLoggedIn; }
   set
   {
       isLoggedIn = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("IsLoggedIn");
   }
}
```

You could then install the [WindowsStateTriggers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsStateTriggers) from nuget

Once you have that installed add a reference at the top of your `xaml` page

```
xmlns:triggers="using:WindowsStateTriggers"
```

next using `VisualStateManager` you can simply show/hide content based on the `IsLoggedIn` property on your viewmodel. Here we target the `Visibility` property of the Grids

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LoginGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="LoggedIn">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:EqualsStateTrigger EqualTo="True" Value="{Binding Path=IsLoggedIn}" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="LoggedInGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Target="LoggedOutGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="LoggedOut">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:EqualsStateTrigger EqualTo="False" Value="{Binding Path=IsLoggedIn}" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="LoggedInGrid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Target="LoggedOutGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid x:Name="LoggedInGrid">                
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="LoggedOutGrid">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>nter code here
```

Comment: thx for your efforts, this would be one opinion, but still I would like to avoid rendering xaml content which will not be used except for the one time where the user enters his credentials

Comment: no worries I will try and think of an alternative. Have a look at [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) as it enables easy navigation in the ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You could check that the credentials are stored/valid when you're loading the application and make a decision whether to navigate to your main app page or a login page from the OnLaunched event in your App.xaml.cs

Comment: I actually began to implement that idea, as you can read in my question, I had the same idea... I am also pretty sure it will work, my main question at the moment is it this the proper way (as microsoft intended it) to handle a one-time login

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the extended splashscreen sample from the sdk: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen